# How do I install timeout package in fedora?

Tags: fedora, yum

I can't find a way to install the `timeout` package using `yum`, just as I could using `apt-get` on Ubuntu.

Comment: what does yum respond the moment it throws the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the /usr/bin/timeout command, it's part of the coreutils package on Fedora, which you should already have:

```
[user@box] yum provides *bin/timeout
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
...
coreutils-7.6-8.fc12.x86_64 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/timeout
```

Comment: In my case the results of abowe command dont match :(
[root@pclab1-62 doalarm-0.1.7]# yum provides *bin/timeout
fedora                    100% |=========================| 2.1 kB    ....
filelists.xml.gz          100% |=========================| 140 kB    00:00     
filelists.sqlite.bz2      100% |=========================| 8.0 MB    03:32     
filelists.sqlite.bz2      100% |=========================| 1.1 kB    00:00     
netatalk.i386 : AppleTalk networking programs

Although I have coreutils.i386 installed.